# PHP Version Looks Wrong

Tags: package-management, php

Despite not installing php5.4, it seems to be the version. Now, Although I delete all php packages on the computer, it still looks the same(5.4).

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
sudo apt-get purge php.*

php -v

PHP 5.4.15 (cli) (built: Aug  8 2018 16:16:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

But I don't want to use PHP 5.4. How can delete php5.4 ?

Comment: *Deleting* packages does not remove installed software. Software must be *removed* or *uninstalled* using the appropriate package manager or uninstall method (depends upon how you installed the software). Please edit your question to clarify exactly what the problem is, and exactly what you have done about it so far.

Comment: what details should I explain more ?

Comment: Updated post. @user535733

Comment: Added @user535733, I'm sorry to late.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php is not from a deb or snap package (they use different locations), so using apt to remove them won't work. You installed php some other way. Please edit your question to show us the output of `ls -la /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1):

When you used `which php` the reply was,

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

It existence within `/usr/local` indicates your PHP was not installed using a package provided by your OS but it was installed manually either by compiling it yourself or by some third party installer.

Thus in order to remove it you'll need to follow the instructions provided with where-ever you originally got it from.

If you simply want to stop the `php` command on the command line from calling up that installation of PHP you can rename that single file, `/usr/local/bin/php` to something like `/usr/local/bin/php-54` or something.  This will stop the name clash with any other PHP version you install from an OS package, but it doesn't uninstall the rest of that PHP installation.

The rule with `/usr/local` is that is a specific area for system-wide software you can install yourself where you are responsible for installation and removal of software, as it is not managed by your OS.